# Need to figure out how to delete from Android Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

alright, So when i call

```
ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lrow, null);
```

which is a delete function for my database, it works and deletes the long i send to it as lrow, the problem i have is then when it deletes the one i pick it leaves all the numbers in the database the same. example i have a list of words 1-10 in a database it shows "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10". I delete number 4 and then in the list showing the word it shows "1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10" - No 4. Is there anyway this can be fixed and have it count the new amount i have and reset the database. so it would show "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

How i get the data is through an array that has each length of the words in my database.

Hope you understand, if not post a comment!

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what the problem is... maybe the numbers you are referring to are some ID for example for your entries in your database?

You could update all the entries with numbers higher than the one you deleted to decrease by one... the [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function will not really work with the ContentValues, but you could try this:

```
ourDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+KEY_ROWID+"="+KEY_ROWID+"-1 WHERE +"KEY_ROWID+">"+lrow);
```

But it's really ugly... I think you should look more at why you need this and is it really necessary...

Comment: Hmm, didnt seem to work. But thanks! i added a plus that you forgot but still not working.

Comment: When I was debugging databases, I was using SQLiteManager extension for Firefox and running the commands there first... maybe you could find out what's going wrong there...